# How to store inside a queue a unique_ptr of object which is located inside a vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, queue, unique-ptr

So I am building a simulator in order to simulate some load balancing algorithms. I have created 2 vectors of Cores and Dispatchers as shown below:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Dispatcher> > vDisp;
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Core> > vCore;
```

The class dispatcher has a queue for the cores in order to assign to them the jobs.

```
std::queue<Core> disp_core_queue;
```

Plus I have some functions in order to handle this queue:

```
void add_core_q(Core& p){ disp_core_queue.push(p); }
Core get_core_q(){ return disp_core_queue.front(); }
```

When the program initializes I populate the cores and disps like this:

```
for (auto i=0; i<dispNumb; ++i)
{
    vDisp.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Dispatcher> (new Dispatcher));
    std::cout<<"Disp n."<<i<<" Created"<<std::endl;
}
```

My problem is that I cannot get a Core from the vector and store it inside a Dispatcher's queue. I have tried many ways but it seems C++ punishes me for various reasons. My last try was this one from inside the Dispatcher:

```
    int kore = random_core();
    this->add_core_q(vCore.at(kore));
```

Which gave this error in compile time:

**error: no matching function for call to 'Dispatcher::add_core_q(_gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits > >::value_type&) '**

*candidate is:*

**void Dispatcher::add_core_q(Core&)**

**no known conversion for argument 1 from '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits > >::value_type {aka std::unique_ptr}' to 'Core&'**

If anyone could give me a hint I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The function signature for add_core_q is taking Core&.
You are passing in a std::unique_ptr.

Answer (score 0):

Your Core objects are stored inside unique_ptr's yet your add_core_q method requires a Core reference.

You could get the raw pointer from the unique_ptr and dereference it which would allow you to do this:

```
add_core_q(*(vCore[0]));
```

However you're also going to have a problem with your get_core_q method since it returns a copy of the Core object rather than a reference to the Core stored in the unique_ptr.

Personally I'd just pass around pointers rather than dereferencing things. So you'd change your add_core_q method to accept a raw pointer:

```
void add_core_q(Core* p){ disp_core_queue.push(p); }
```

Which you would use like this:

```
add_core_q(vCore[0].get());
```

You'd also have to change your queue to store pointers rather than the objects themselves:

```
std::queue<Core*> disp_core_queue;
```

And you'll need to change the return type of your get method to a pointer.

```
Core* get_core_q(){ return disp_core_queue.front(); }
```

Though if you're more comfortable with references you could return a reference instead:

```
Core& get_core_q(){ return *(disp_core_queue.front()); }
```

Comment: I tried your approach but gcc would not agree. During compile time throws an error at *stl_deque.h* .

**typedef _Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Tp&, _Tp*>             iterator;**

This happens when i change my queue to store references.

Comment: Yeh sorry about that, I was having a stupid moment, it should be a queue of pointers. I've amended the answer.